# Clone Bitbucket repository without starting ssh-agent

Tags: jenkins, ssh, bitbucket

I've set up Jenkins on my VPS and created a job which is set to execute a shell script containing the following command: `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org`

It turns out that i get a "Permission denied (publickey)." response because ssh-agent is not started. This can be solved by adding these two lines to the shell script:

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add ~/.ssh/bitbucket_key
```

However, I don't like to add these tho lines to every Jenkins item when I need to clone a repository. I would expect that if I log in via ssh to my VPS and change to the Jenkins user to execute the two lines myself, this would no longer be necessary. Unfortunately, this is not the case. I can successfully run `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` myself, but the Jenkins job still fails without the two extra lines.

Is there a way to avoid this behavior, i.e. a way in which I only have to start the ssh-agent and add my key to it once instead of every time I want to clone a repository? I cannot imagine that it would be a good practice to start (a new) ssh-agent every time I want to clone and build my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ssh_config` in your `~/.ssh/config`. It has simple syntax as you can read in manual page for `ssh_config`. For your case should be enough

```
Host bitbucket.org
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bitbucket_key
```

Comment: That helped! I solved it (temporary) by adding a new clobal credential to Jenkins which pointed to the key, but that requires me to add this credentials to every new job. This solution allows me to always pull from my repository, regardless the job.